# ajax comments show on submit w / out page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote the beginnings of a very simple comment system.  It uses jQuery / AJAX / PHP MySQL.  So far it works fine.  But, once a comment is submitted you have to refresh the page to show the comment.  How can it show on submit.

I hope this isn't too much code here, but here it is in three parts.  The jQuery / the php insert comment query / the php select comments query.

jQuery / AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    if(name == '' || comment == '') {
        $('#comment_messages').html('Please enter both fields');
    } else if(name !== '' || comment !== '') {
        $('#comment_messages').html('');

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'comments.php',
    data: 'name='+name+'&comment='+comment,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#comments_area').append(data);
    }
    });
    }
  });
});
```

PHP INSERT (to insert comments):

```
<?php

include('init.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['comment'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  if(!empty($name) && !empty($comment)) {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(NULL, '$name', '$comment', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    if($query === true) {

      // right here is what is being returned to success: function(data) in the ajax script.  What's the best way to return the comment here? 

    } else {
      echo 'Hmmm... that\'s odd........';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Please enter both fields';
  }
}

?>
```

PHP SELECT (to retrieve comments):

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");

  $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($num >= 1) {
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $name = $fetch['name'];
      $comment = $fetch['comment'];
      $time = $fetch['time'];

      ?>

        <div id="user_comments">

          <?php echo $name; ?> said at: <span id="time_stamp"><?php echo $time; ?></span><p>- <?php echo $comment; ?>

        </div>

      <?php

    }
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Added two lines at bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    if(name == '' || comment == '') {
        $('#comment_messages').html('Please enter both fields');
    } else if(name !== '' || comment !== '') {
        $('#comment_messages').html('');

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'comments.php',
    data: 'name='+name+'&comment='+comment,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#comments_area').append('<b>'+name+'</b><p>- '+comment);
    $('#comment_messages').html(data);
    }
    });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the comment when you send it, so when the AJAX call to submit the comment returns a successful, you can just append the comment without actually getting it from PHP/AJAX.

So don't return the comment, that's just data which isn't actually going to be used.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'comments.php',
data: 'name='+name+'&comment='+comment,
success: function(data) {
$('#comments_area').append('<b>'+name+'</b>: '+comment);
}
});
}
});
```

And return a 200 statuscode in your PHP file if succes, or a 4xx statuscode if fail. This way only when a 200 statuscode is returned, it will go into the `succes:` block

Instead of appending the comment like above, you could also use jQuery templates ( http://api.jquery.com/template/).

Filter by statuscode too: (doc on this page): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Catch failure like in example below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    // add comment here, succes will go here if ajax returns a 200 statuscode
  }
  error: function(){
    // add failure here, error will go there if ajax returns a 4xx statuscode
  }
});
```

If you want to use the statuscodes, take a look at this example:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
        //succes
    },
    400: function(){
        // bad request
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great idea. But you should create a SUCCES/FAILURE structure then right? Cause wont it succed loading the page, even if the comments fails being inserted into the Database? :)

Comment: you should return PHP headers, a 200 if success and a 4xx when fail. This way it will not end up in succes block

Comment: I liked this approach.  I also added the SUCCESS / FAILURE beneath the line of code you suggested (see in the UPDATE).  Is this scalable / secure / common practice?  It just seems like it will get very cluttered in that append() tag.  It just seems kind of messy.

Comment: U could also use the combination of jQuery ajax statuscodes (look it up here) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and template: http://api.jquery.com/template/

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'comments.php',
data: 'name='+name+'&comment='+comment,
success: function(data) {
    $('#comments_area').append(data);
    $('user_comments').load('selectcomments.php #user_comments')
}
```

Then it would save the entry, and reload the comment section.

But you should set #user_comments as a container ID, and never use ID's for a repeating element.

So i would do

```
<div id="user_comments">
        <div class="comment">comment info here</div>
        <div class="comment">comment info here</div>
        <div class="comment">comment info here</div>
        <div class="comment">comment info here</div>
</div>
```

And then in your Comment Insert on SUCCES i would do a SUCCES messeage for the user.

Answer (score 1):

@Graham, as stated by Topener you can do or in addition what can you do is that as `ajax()` response send one numeric code

```
if(//name and comment empty){
  echo "0";
} else if (// name and comment not inserted to db table){
  echo "1";
} else if (//successful){
  echo "2";
}
```

now based on this ajax response you can code for java-script i.e

```
if(response == '0'){
  $('#comment_messages').html('Please enter both fields');
} elseif (response == '1'){
  $('#comment_messages').html('Hmmm... that\'s odd........');
} elseif (response == '2'){
  $('#comments_area').append('<b>'+name+'</b>: '+comment);
}
```

Hope you get it.

Comment: would even be better just to use statuscodes, so you don't need to do the logic yourself on checking for input

Comment: @Topener  Can you please give me one example to work with status code?